# Getting Error like uses unchecked or unsafe operations

Tags: java

Getting error uses unchecked or unsafe operations. after I update me some android studio firebase libraries.

Getting error in logcat is ...
uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

```
public class UserId
{
    public String userId;
    public<T extends UserId> T withDocId(@Nullable final String id)
    {
        this.userId=id;
        return (T) this;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details?

Answer (score 1):

A cast to a type parameter is an unsafe typecast.  In fact in this case, the typecheck that happens at runtime is

```
return (UserId) this;
```

But wait.  The type of `this` is `UserId` ... and the type parameter is not achieving anything.  The class could be simplified to this:

```
public class UserId {
    public String userId;
    public UserId withDocId(@Nullable final String id) {
        this.userId = id;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`(T)` is not safe, because in Java, generic types are subject to *type erasure,* which means they act as *compile-time only* type safety enforcement.  At runtime, there is no class named `T`, so it is not possible for a compiler to generate a bytecode instruction that can cast to `T`.

Since there is no way to know at compile-time what the type of `this` actually is (aside from knowing that it has to be UserId or a descendant class of UserId), you can’t apply a generic type to `this`.

You could let the user pass the type that they expect the UserId to be, though it’s rather awkward:

```
public <T extends UserId> T withDocId(@Nullable final String id,
                                      Class<T> userIdType)
{
    this.userId = id;
    return userIdType.cast(this);
}
```

Another possibility is overriding the methods in each subclass.

```
public class UserId
{
    public UserId withDocId(@Nullable final String id)
    {
        this.userId = id;
        return this;
    }
}

public class ManagerId
extends UserId
{
    @Override
    public ManagerId withDocId(@Nullable final String id)
    {
        super.withDocId(id);
        return this;
    }
}
```

This is permitted because a subclass returning a smaller set of types is fully compatible with the superclass definition.